# Shipping cart rule not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have set $40 as flat shipping and I want that if anyone purchase above or equal $50 then the flat shipping become 0. So I am setting this rule for the purpose:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal  equals or greater than  50
```

and for action:

[image]

But there is a strange issue:

Case 1: If I buy 1 product of $25 then there is shipping of $40 (Correct)

Case 2: If I buy 3 * 25 then subtotal is $75 and shipping is 0 (Correct)

Case 3: If I buy 1 product of $80 then the subtotal is displaying as $40 and free shipping too(Incorrect)

So I want to correct the result of Case 3 that price should be remain $80 but the shipping should be free only. Please help to get this. Thank you

Comment: Why you set the discount amount 40?

Comment: As my flatrate shipping is $40 and I want it to set 0 if purchase >= 50 so I set discount to $40.

Comment: Please help me to resolve this as All I want to do is set free shipping if subtotal >=50

Comment: you want free shipping and $40 discount both?

Comment: If you want only free shipping then please remove $40 and check

Comment: @kayurshah Thank you I set discount to 0 and its working fine for all three conditions.

Comment: I added the answer from the comment section :) glad that it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment you need to remove the 40 from the Discount Amount section to make it working.

Comment: Please can you briefly explain the"Apply to shipping amount" and "Free Shipping" columns. I cant understand their values.